# How to override FormHelperText styles in React Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React [**Material-UI**](https://material-ui.com/) library and don't understand how to override FormHelperText styles?

```
const { classes } = this.props
...
<TextField
  name='username'
  label='Username'
  error={this.state.usernameInvalid}
  helperText={this.state.usernameError}
  classes={{
    root: classes.textField,
    FormHelperText: classes.helperText // <-- how to override by right way?
  }}
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
/>
...
export default withStyles(styles)(SignInPopup)
```

styles:

```
const styles = () => ({
  textField: {
    width: '100%'
  },
  helperText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: '-50%'
  }
})
```

I've got this error:

```
Warning: Material-UI: the key `FormHelperText` provided to the classes property is not implemented in FormControl.
You can only override one of the following: root,marginNormal,marginDense,fullWidth
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution is here:

```
<TextField
  name='username'
  label='Username'
  className={classes.textField}
  error={this.state.usernameInvalid}
  helperText={this.state.usernameError}
  FormHelperTextProps={{ classes: { root: classes.helperText } }} // <- smth like that
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be the solution for styling this prop:

```
const styles = {
    helper: {
         color: 'blue',
         fontSize: '.8em',
    }
}

return(
   <TextField
     ...
     FormHelperTextProps={{ style: styles.helper }}
   />
);
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add styling:
`FormHelperTextProps={{ style: { color: theme.palette.metalgrey.main } }}`